# PHP dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: php, dynamicform

I'm trying to create a dropdown list which has the pre-selected value determined by a file. Unfortunately I'm not sure I'm getting the syntax right. Here's what I have so far:

```
<select id="SampleRate", name="SampleRate">

    <?php

    $controller_file = 'controllerSetup.conf';
    $comment = "#";
    $fp = fopen($controller_file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $line = trim(fgets($fp));
        if ($line && !ereg("^$comment", $line)) {
            $pieces = explode("=", $line);
            $option = trim($pieces[0]);
            $value = trim($pieces[1]);
            $controller_values[$option] = $value;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $sampleRates = array("48", "96", "192", "350");
    foreach ($sampleRates as $r) {
        if ($r == $controller_values["SampleRate"]) {
            echo ("<option value=$r selected>selected</option>");
        } else {
            echo ("<option value=$r>not selected</option>");
        }
    };
    ?>

</select>
```

Unfortunately, looking at the html produced in my browser, only one "not selected" option is produced. How do I get this to produce four options? I've tried replacing the "if" statement in the foreach with a simple `if ($r == "48")`, to no avail. Is my syntax around the echo statements correct?

Comment: Use double quotes `"` around your HTML attribute values: `echo '<option value="' , $r , '" selected>selected</option>';` and don't write brackets around language constructs like `echo`.

Comment: should you be using `selected="selected"` within the selected `<option>` tag

Comment: @Chris write just `selected` as of HTML5 standard is perfectly fine.

Comment: Tried that, still produces one option only:

    if ($r == "48") {
        echo '<option value="$r" selected>selected</option>';
       } else {
        echo '<option value="$r">not selected</option>';
       }

Comment: (As a side note, how do I format that code as, well, code? It's all been stuck on a single line here...)